# Rails App on AWS EB: Migrations fail

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Having trouble setting up a AWS RDS for my Rails app running on Elastic Beanstalk. I followed [the docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.RDS.html), but when it tries to run migrations, I get MySQL syntax errors.  Pretty sure I don't have syntax errors because the migrations run fine locally and I successfully setup a staging and the errors are on the first line.  I was thinking it might have to do with the security group blocking traffic, but I updated my inbound rules appropriately and still get the errors:

```
3306    tcp 173.8.166.54/32, sg-3221b354     <- RDs Security Group
80      tcp 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0, sg-3b31a75d        
22      tcp 0.0.0.0/0       
443     tcp 0.0.0.0/0
```

I have my environment variables set for the db.  What am I missing?

The errors I'm getting:  Occurs on the first line of the first migration

> Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'json, `image` varchar(255), `code` varchar(255), `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,' at line 1: CREATE TABLE `coupons` (`id` int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, `product` varchar(255), `offer` varchar(255), `size` varchar(255), `description` varchar(255), `info` json, `image` varchar(255), `code` varchar(255), `created_at` datetime NOT NULL, `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL) ENGINE=InnoDB
>     /var/app/ondeck/db/migrate/20170725193230_create_coupons.rb:3:in `change'
>     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.4/bin/bundle:22:in`load'
>     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.4/bin/bundle:22:in `<main>'
>     ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'json,`image`varchar(255),`code`varchar(255),`created_at`datetime NOT NULL,' at line 1: CREATE TABLE`coupons`(`id`int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,`product`varchar(255),`offer`varchar(255),`size`varchar(255),`description`varchar(255),`info`json,`image`varchar(255),`code`varchar(255),`created_at`datetime NOT NULL,`updated_at`datetime NOT NULL) ENGINE=InnoDB
>     /var/app/ondeck/db/migrate/20170725193230_create_coupons.rb:3:in`change'
>     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.4/bin/bundle:22:in `load'
>     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.4/bin/bundle:22:in`'
>     Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'json, `image` varchar(255), `code` varchar(255), `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,' at line 1
>     /var/app/ondeck/db/migrate/20170725193230_create_coupons.rb:3:in `change'

migration in question:

```
class CreateCoupons < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :coupons do |t|
      t.string :product
      t.string :offer
      t.string :size
      t.string :description
      t.json :info
      t.string :image
      t.string :code

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Which Security group are you showing rules for? The instance? or RDS? is sg-3221b354 the sec group for your RDS instance or EB instances?

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: @Brian updated with errors

Comment: @strongjz  I am showing the inbound rules for my instance.  It includes 2 security groups, the one created for the instance and the one created for the rds.  The rds sg has a rule for itself on 3306.  I followed the steps in the docs.

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with your security groups. Are you running the same version of MySQL locally as you are in RDS?

Comment: @Brian, I'll look.

Comment: @Brian, thanks, you were right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the mysql version on the rds was wrong.  AWS defaulted to 5.6.  I upgraded to 5.7.17 and everything works.